# How to merge two different Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, help-center, merge-accounts

I know that a similar question (*How to merge two different **Stack Overflow** accounts?*) was asked a lot of times, but the answer to all of them was the same: visit the [help centre page on merging accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) and use the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/submit) with the `I need to merge user profiles` option selected.

Unfortunately, I want neither to merge two Stack Overflow account nor to merge a Stack Overflow account with a Stack Exchange account. And the solution seems to work only in the second case.

What I should do if I want to merge two different Stack Exchange accounts?

Comment: The same  thing.

Comment: @Rob Doesn't work, otherwise I would not have posted the question.

Comment: @gvgramazio I don't understand. Can you clarify what is not working? Did you submit the contact form, and haven't had a reply yet, or were you unable to submit the form at all?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I want to merge two accounts on the whole SE network. The instructions I've found so far are relative only to accounts on the same community. Should I submit a contact form for each community?

Comment: Ah. I think the best you can do is join the same community as your other account, with the account you want to keep. **Don't interact with the account you already have there**. Then fill in the contact form, and request the account merge, so the account can be added to your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5968374/gvgramazio?tab=accounts)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I was very cautious and I never interacted between the two accounts because I known that I could have encountered problems in a future merge. The older one is for personal use and the other one for work related questions. I realised that it was a very stupid idea and now I wish to merge them.

Comment: So do you want them to be completely merged, or just for 1 community? From what I can see over here, it does not seem you have to perform this for every community, you can just pick a site and they'll merge them entirely.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I want them to be completely merged. I did it now with the form at https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact and it worked.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell New issue: I'm able to login with both email at the same account now (this is what I hoped for)  but when I look at the profile settings I see only one email.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Nevermind, found both of them now. It is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out :) You're welcome!